# How do I intigrade C++ code with React Native JSI

Tags: c++, react-native, android-ndk, react-native-jsi, react-native-turbomodule

> I want to use C++ code to write algorithms in both android & ios apps, can I do it with the help of react native JSI what is the step by step process of integrating C++ Code in my React Native Project

Comment: https://blog.notesnook.com/getting-started-react-native-jsi/